# Is creating an extra node when solving linked list question a good habit?

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Lately, I've been working on linked list questions on LeetCode, and I noticed that when dealing with linked lists (like sorting linked lists), people sometimes create a **dummy node** and return `dummy->next`. It is a pretty convenient act, but are there any bad outcomes from doing this (*say, if I will delete it in the end to avoid a memory leak*)? Or, are there any situations that make this act inappropriate?

The code below is an example, `ohead` is my **dummy** node:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* oddEvenList(ListNode* head) {
        ListNode *ohead = new ListNode, *ehead = new ListNode;
        ListNode *optr  = ohead, *eptr = ehead;
        bool isOdd = true;
        for(auto ptr = head; ptr; ptr = ptr->next){
            if(isOdd){
                optr->next = ptr;
                optr = optr->next;
            }
            else{
                eptr->next = ptr;
                eptr = eptr->next;
            }
            isOdd = !isOdd; //update isOdd
        }
        optr->next = ehead->next;
        eptr->next = nullptr;
        return (ohead->next);
    }
};
```

Comment: This is frequently referred to as using a sentinel node, and it is a recognized as a good technique - if it simplifies your logic, go for it, but yes, you do need to remember to free it with the container if it's dynamically allocated.

Comment: @CataCaster The function has memory leaks. There is no any need to create dummy nodes in your function.

Comment: @CataCaster Pay attention to that in C++ indices start from 0. So the first node of the list is even and the second node of the list is odd.

Comment: This code is indeed leaking memory, but it is also modifying the input list that `head` points to, rather than making a copy of that list's values and putting them in odd/even order. What is the actual purpose of the challenge? To re-sort the input list, or to return a new list? It makes a big difference.

Comment: because this is tagged as c++ and not c: `std::unique_ptr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, creating a new node has no problem. Because all it matters in solving LeetCode questions is the efficiency of your algorithm (time and memory complexity). Adding one new node is constant time and memory and would not change the complexity of your solution.

Here is an O(N) time and O(1) space solution that would pass LeetCode's "Online Judge" for the problem you're trying to solve:

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* oddEvenList(ListNode* head) {
        if (!head) {
            return head;
        }

        ListNode* odd = head;
        ListNode* even_head = head->next;
        ListNode* even = even_head;

        while (even && even->next) {
            odd->next = odd->next->next;
            even->next = even->next->next;
            odd = odd->next;
            even = even->next;
        }

        odd->next = even_head;

        return head;
    }
};
```

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/odd-even-linked-list/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions, explanations, efficient algorithms with a variety of languages, and time/space complexity analysis in there.
- [328. Odd Even Linked List](https://leetcode.com/problems/odd-even-linked-list/)
- [328. Odd Even Linked List - Discussion](https://leetcode.com/problems/odd-even-linked-list/discuss/)